# Gradle overwriting general transitive=false for specific dependency

Tags: gradle, dependencies

After playing around a little bit with gradle i stumbled upon the following behavior and i'm not sure if this is as intended or if i'm doing something wrong.

I am exlcuding all transitive dependencies by default with telling the compile configuration `transitive false`. But for a specific dependency i just want to include the transitive dependencies , so i added `transitive true` to the dependency declaration.

But as it happens, gradle ignores my overwrite.

Is this as intended? Am i doing something wrong?

Following is an example:

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    compile {
            transitive false
    }
    testCompile {
            transitive false
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12') { transitive true }
}
```

### output

#### including transitive dependencies per default

```
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

testCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.404 secs
```

#### excluding transitive dependencies per default but including it for specific dependency

```
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

testCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
\--- junit:junit:4.12

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.352 secs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can do that because you already declared that configuration to exclude transitive dependencies.  The other pattern I see is the other way around, include transitive and exclude in the declaration of dependency.

```
configurations {
    compile {
            transitive false
    }
    testCompile {
            transitive false
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12') { exclude module: 'exclude.this' }
}
```

or change the configuration to exclude everything but the one you want

Comment: yes, the other way around is working and that is why i think it _should_ work my way too. Just to be consistent.

Comment: thanks to the good "similiar topics"- function on the gradle user forum i found that it is indeed an leftover from ivy and works just this way right now. See [link](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/problem-with-fine-tuning-transitive-dependency-management/1634). Marked this as answered.